# I need to upload multiple images via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

I am a bit of a beginner, and I am trying to create a feature that allows users to make a slideshow of photos. They upload the images and see a preview using this code:

```
function photoPreview (input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('.preview-photo').attr('src', e.target.result);

        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$('.photo-upload').change(function(){
    photoPreview(this);
})
```

and then click an 'add' button to add the photo to the image queue that is below the preview div. The image queue shows a snapshot of the photo using this code:

```
var uploadSource = $('.preview-photo').attr('src');
$('#queue-container').append("<img class='snapshot-photo'" + "src='" + uploadSource + "'>");
```

Finally, I try to send all the photos via ajax.

```
for (i = 0; i < $('#queue-container').children('.snapshot-photo').length; i++) {
    var sourcevalue = $('#snapshot-container').children('.snapshot-photo:eq(' + i + ')').attr('src')
    var source = document.createElement('input');
    $(source).attr({
        type: 'file',
        name: 'photo_source_' + i,
        value: sourcevalue
    });
}
```

When I get to my server-side and try to see if it has gone through using the file system, it comes out as undefined

```
fs.readFileSync(req.files.photo_source_0) // cannot read property of undefined
```

I know it's a long question, but I really need the help. How can I get the file system of node to recognize the files? Or is my whole process wrong? All suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Hope this will help you http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: I'm guessing you have server side set up with Node.js and `express()`. Post how the route is set up and post the (client) code for submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use from [Uploadfiy](http://www.uploadify.com/), it have very complete options for you and have two version, flash version (is free) and HTML5 version that you can buy this version.